# Bulk change of URIs in RDF/OWL ontologies

Tags: rdf, jena, owl

I am writing a program which cleans up ontology files (OWL files) which were created manually using Protege. The problem is that (among other issues) the manually created files have the wrong base URIs.

Is there a way to change the ontology file's base URI or should I change the URI of each individual independently? Could somebody guide me on how I could do that using Apache Jena?

example file:

```
<rdf:RDF
  xmlns="http://www.semanticweb.org/pnatsiavas/ontologies/input_ontology"
  xml:base="http://www.semanticweb.org/pnatsiavas/ontologies/input_ontology"
  ...
  xmlns:input_ontology="http://www.semanticweb.org/pnatsiavas/ontologies/input_ontology#"

  <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/pnatsiavas/ontologies/input_ontology#individual1">
  <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/pnatsiavas/ontologies/reference_ontology#Class1"/>
  </owl:NamedIndividual>
  ...
```

Could I change the http://www.semanticweb.org/pnatsiavas/ontologies/input_ontology URI to something else using Apache Jena? I would like to change the file's base URI to update all individuals of the ontology at once, but even if this is not possible, I should be able to change the URI of each individual separately (see the following snippet). Right? However, I cannot find a "setURI" method. Am I missing something?

```
List<Individual> individuals =
inputOntology.listIndividuals().toList();
for(Individual individual: inputOntology){
    individual.asNode().setURI(newURI); // setURI method does not exist
}
```

Comment: Just change the URI of each individual by using a SPARQL Update `DELETE {...} INSERT {...} WHERE {...}` query: https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-update/#deleteInsert

Comment: or just use a text editor and do regex replacement. Would be even more efficient and straightforward

Comment: There is also `org.apache.jena.util.ResourceUtils#renameResource(Resource, String)` in jena-core